# Sum numbers with comma in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to sum my column (`Calculated Cash`) using PHPExcel. The problem is the numbers are typed as **string**... I don't want to remove the commas to leave numbers user-friendly.

Can you help me with finding sum on the column?

[image]

Here's my code:

```php
    $sql = "
        SELECT a.DOB as `DATE`,
        FORMAT(a.Amount,2) AS CALCULATED 
        FROM deposit a 
        WHERE STR_TO_DATE(a.DOB, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '20170701' AND '20170701';
    ";

    $rowCount = 2;  
    $rowTop = 3;
    $rowMinus = $rowCount - 1;

    $objPHPExcel
        ->getActiveSheet()
        ->setCellValue('D'.$rowCount, '=SUM(D'.$rowTop.':D'.$rowMinus.')');

    $objPHPExcel
        ->getActiveSheet()
        ->getStyle('D'.$rowCount)
        ->applyFromArray($styleBold);

     $objPHPExcel
        ->getActiveSheet()
        ->getStyle('D3:D4')
        ->getNumberFormat()
        ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_GENERAL);
```

Comment: set number as float and do cell format(using PHP Excel function if any) to show the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer I'm looking for :)

I've got rid of the FORMAT({columnname},2) when I'm calling my result in my database and  added this code to my PHPexcel :)

Code:

```
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('H'.$rowCount)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER_COMMA_SEPARATED1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Some tricks about php:

```
$a = "4,";
$b = "5 soldiers";
echo $a + $b; // returns 9
```

So php is a weak type language and checks if needed converts string to integer!

If you had something like this you can convert it's numbers to a array of numbers:

```
$val = ", 2, ,4 ,5 , 6"; // a string of numbers
$parts = explode(",",$val); // an array of numbers
```

So $parts would be like:

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(1) " 2" [2]=> string(1) " " [3]=> string(2) " 4" [4]=> string(2) " 5" [5]=> string(2) " 6" }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer :) , however, I'm looking for how to sum my column... not declaring a variable to each number since these numbers are now in the database I'm working on :(

Comment: @Rukikun How is your variables to calculate? Or your question is how to get that variables?

Comment: my variables that I'm declaring are just for the positioning of my cells in Excel format

Comment: So you should  check setCellValue method to make sume changes in it!